# Convert days to months and days in php

Tags: php

I have a number 144 i want to convert to months and days, i.e. I want to display 3 months 24 days.

What is the formula to do it? I have tried many methods but no use.

```
$sub_struct_month = ($result[0] / 30) ;
$sub_struct_month = floor($sub_struct_month); 
$sub_struct_days = ($result[0] / 30); // the rest of days
$sub_struct = $sub_struct_month."m ".$sub_struct_days."d";
```

Comment: Well, that's a difficult question. Because you need to know what month you're talking about and if the year is a leap year. With just the number 144, you can't make a reliable prediction.

Comment: Your example of 144 give 4 months and 24 days

Comment: Period from where?. Is it beginig of year or from given date?

Comment: Posted answer using Modulus. Does just that.

Answer (score 7):

Use the Modulus operator to get the proper number of days:

```
<?php
$result = array(144);

$sub_struct_month = ($result[0] / 30) ;
$sub_struct_month = floor($sub_struct_month); 
$sub_struct_days = ($result[0] % 30); // the rest of days
$sub_struct = $sub_struct_month."m ".$sub_struct_days."d";

echo $sub_struct;
?>
```

Results in `4m 24d`.

More details: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 5):

You know that there are leapyears (February has 29 days sometimes)? And for example July and August have 31 days. You can't say generally "convert 144 days to months" because it's different for every month.

```
<?php
$start_date = new DateTime(date("Y/m/d"));
$end_date = new DateTime(date("Y/m/d",strtotime("+144 days")));
$dd = date_diff($start_date,$end_date);
echo "$dd->m months $dd->d days";
?>
```

for start_date you can use a specific date! also for end_date
this is the correct way, so every leapyear and everything is observed!

Comment: Got it! There you go!

Answer (score 0):

please try below code

```
  $months = floor(144 / 30);
  $days = 144 - ($months*30);
  echo  $months ."Months " . $days ."days";
```

Comment: what about 28 / 29 / 31 days ??

Comment: She need general months calculation.

Comment: where she specified that " She want general month calculation"

Comment: But if you check the value which she gave.

Comment: See Modulus Operator. `144 % 30 = 24`

Answer (score 0):

PHP has perfect class to work with dates: [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

This class allow you get difference between two dates [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) and format result as you want using [DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Yes, it's not exactly what you want. But it allow you get **precise** value of days and months.

So, I suggest you read the docs at first. I hope you will find a way how to implement it in your case.

Answer (score -1):

My way to do it

```
$days = 144;

$month = $days/30;

list($month,$days) = explode(".",$month);
$days = "0.".$days;
echo $month."</br>";
echo $days*30;
```